# How can i use the lockforupdate in laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, locking

Welcome all ,
I have   problem  in laravel 4  , when using lock for update statement
i want to prevent two  users from updating the same record using
RESTful Resource Controllers and Pessimistic Locking.
Here is my view of edit

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $_get['id'])->lockForUpdate()->first();
```

and i want to check if row is locked before open edit page
Regards

Comment: Do it in a transaction.

Comment: plz could you help me with code as i do it with transactions but nothing changes